# Safest way to run BAT file from Powershell script

Tags: batch-file, powershell

I can not get a powershell script to execute a bat file directly. For example, this works on the command line:

```
.\\my-app\my-fle.bat
```

When I add this command to a script, it outputs:

```
The term '.\\my-app\my-file.bat' is not recognized as the 
name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I also tried the following, with the same result:

```
& .\\my-app\my-fle.bat
& ".\\my-app\my-fle.bat"
\my-app\my-fle.bat
& \my-app\my-fle.bat
& "\my-app\my-fle.bat"
```

Note: It must return the lastexitcode as I need to verify success of batch.

Comment: Two backslashes indicate a server share.

Comment: What did you mean by safest?

Answer (score 133):

```
cmd.exe /c '\my-app\my-file.bat'
```

Comment: How do I add an argument to the bat file here? Specifically if the argument is a variable? I tried this[Start-Process `"cmd.exe" "/B /C test.bat $inputFilePath`"], but it says: "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'test.bat'."

Comment: @Horizon - Specify each of your arguments in an array of strings with the -ArgumentList parameter: `Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList @("/B", "/C", "test.bat", "$inputFilePath");`  It's important to note that the value of `$inputFilePath` is interpreted like it would be directly in DOS. E.g. a value of "a\b c\d e\f.txt" would cause test.bat to see %1="a\b", %2="c\d", and %3="e\f.txt"

Comment: Oh. Forgot: Technically, [the .bat and all of its arguments are considered a single argument to cmd.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html), so if you have spaces in the path to "test.bat" it gets more complicated. To be safe, surround your entire DOS command in double-quotes and DOS-escape the quotes you actually wanted to use before you found out you had to do this extra step. E.g. ```Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList @("/B", "/C", "`"", "^`"test.bat^`"", "^`"$inputFilePath^`"", "`"");```

Answer (score 51):

To run the .bat, and have access to the last exit code, run it as:

```
 & .\my-app\my-fle.bat
```

Comment: That only works when `my-app` is in the relative path or I use the drive letter. I was trying to avoid tying to the script to specific drive.

Comment: @Casey I guess I misunderstood. So `my-app` is a folder at the root of whatever drive you're working with? If so, `& \my-app\my-file.bat` works for me. How are you calling the .ps1 script?

Comment: What's wrong with just invoking it directly? On Windows 10 using PowerShell 7.2.6, invoking e.g. `mvn clean build` from inside a `.ps1` script seems to work just fine. In this case `mvn` is the `mvn.cmd` script on the path.

Answer (score 29):

Try this, your dot source was a little off.  Edit, adding lastexitcode bits for OP.

```
$A = Start-Process -FilePath .\my-app\my-fle.bat -Wait -passthru;$a.ExitCode
```

add `-WindowStyle Hidden` for invisible batch.

Comment: That worked. Will this also return the exit status in LastExitCode?

Comment: to access $lastexitcode from start-process, you'll need to assisn the command to a variable and use the passthru switch, then read exitcode from variable.

Answer (score 16):

You can simply do:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\PathToBatFile\FileToExecute.bat" -ArgumentList $argstr -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

*Here,*

**ArgumentList** - to pass parameters or parameter values if needed by bat file

**Wait** - waits for the process(bat) to complete

**NoNewWindow** - starts the new process in the current console window.

Comment: For -ArgumentList see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process?view=powershell-7.2#example-7--specifying-arguments-to-the-process)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming my-app is a subdirectory under the current directory.  The $LASTEXITCODE should be there from the last command:

```
.\my-app\my-fle.bat
```

If it was from a fileshare:

```
\\server\my-file.bat
```

Answer (score 3):

What about `invoke-item script.bat`.

Comment: What about it, indeed?

Answer (score 0):

@Rynant 's solution worked for me. I had a couple of additional requirements though:

1. Don't PAUSE if encountered in bat file
2. Optionally, append bat file output to log file

Here's what I got working (finally):

[PS script code]

```
& runner.bat bat_to_run.bat logfile.txt
```

[runner.bat]

```
@echo OFF

REM This script can be executed from within a powershell script so that the bat file
REM passed as %1 will not cause execution to halt if PAUSE is encountered.
REM If {logfile} is included, bat file output will be appended to logfile.
REM
REM Usage:
REM runner.bat [path of bat script to execute] {logfile}

if not [%2] == [] GOTO APPEND_OUTPUT
@echo | call %1
GOTO EXIT

:APPEND_OUTPUT
@echo | call %1  1> %2 2>&1

:EXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

Even using [win_shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_shell_module.html) ansible module this can be achieved:

```
- name: Install the WebApp Service
  win_shell: 'Service_Install.bat'
  args:
    executable: cmd
    chdir: 'D:\MyWebApp\Services'
  register: result
```

Here `D:\MyWebApp\Services` is the location where your `.bat` file is available.