# Start-Job - check $lastexicode of robocopy inside a Scriptblock

Tags: powershell, robocopy, start-job, scriptblock

I'm trying to do something simple.

I want to create a robocopy job that would launch the copy and check the $lastexitcode.

```
$Source = "c:\SourceFolder"
$Destination "\\someserver\Destinationfolder"

$ScriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create("robocopy $Source $Destination /MOVE /E /R:5 /E /W:5 /A-:SH; if ( $lastexitcode -gt 8) { LOGMESSAGE ERROR } else { LOGMESSAGE SUCCESS }")

start-job -scriptblock $ScriptBlock
```

LOGMESSAGE is a function i've written that will log the event and send a mail in case of error.

Somehow, the $lastexitcode value is always returned to 16 - Even when the copy works.
Also, The function is not executed (it works outside of the scriptblock)

Does anybody have a clue on what I am doing wrong ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: Why not just use start-process?  e.g. $robocopy = start-process robocopy -argumentlist <arguments> -passthru.  That will return a process object with HasExited and ExitCode properties you can check to see if it's finished and what the exit code was.

Comment: here is how I lastexitcode from start-process  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645326/safest-way-to-run-bat-file-from-powershell-script/20645421#20645421

Comment: Hi, First off thanks for your help ! I have tried to use start-process as Knuckle-Dragger showed but the exit code returned is always 1... Even if the copy works. I must be missing something here.

Comment: Nope, it worked perfectly! **ExitCode 0 = No Errors, No Files Copied** So ExitCode 1 is actually a good thing. **ExitCode 1 = No Errors, New Files Copied**. ExitCode > 1 = There were errors, or at least unexpected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See your comment, guessing you've found success.  Here is the answer for future readers in case the link I've quoted goes down.   Basically we are assigning the start-process command to a variable and throwing the `-passthru` tag so we can poll for the `.exitcode` later.

```
$A = Start-Process -FilePath .\my-app\my-fle.bat -Wait -passthru
$A.ExitCode
```