# Run a batch file in an externam CMD window from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a PowerShell script that runs on startup and creates a couple of batch files.  I need to create the batch files (as opposed to run them directly) as they are required for use by users at a later time.

This PowerShell script should then run each of these batch files in there own CMD window, as these CMD windows will persist until the server is shutdown.

While I can get a new CMD window to appear for each batch file, I can't seem to get them to run my batch files.  What am I doing wrong?

```
###
 # Grab the WebDriver folder and the public IP of this server
 ##
$webDriverFolder = "C:\WebDriver"
$WebDriverHubFilePath = "$webDriverFolder\Launch WebDriver Hub.bat"
$WebDriverIENodeFilePath = "$webDriverFolder\Launch WebDriver InternetExplorer Node 1.bat"
$publicIP = (Invoke-WebRequest ifconfig.me/ip).content

###
 # Generate the batch file contents
 ##
$webDriverHubStr = "batch file stuff"
$WebDriverIENodeStr = "different batch file stuff"

###
 # Generate up to date WebDriver batch files (with the correct IP and folder path)
 ##
$webDriverHubStr | Out-File "$WebDriverHubFilePath"
$WebDriverIENodeStr | Out-File "$WebDriverIENodeFilePath"

###
 # Run the commands to launch WebDriver Hub and IE Node 1
 ##
Start-Process cmd.exe "$WebDriverHubFilePath"
Start-Process cmd.exe "$WebDriverIENodeFilePath"
```

Comment: Have you searched any? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645326/safest-way-to-run-bat-file-from-powershell-script

Comment: No, I manually configure Google to ignore Stack Overflow when searching for solutions to coding problems, just to waste everyone's time. /sarcasm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Start-Process -FilePath cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/c $WebDriverHubFilePath"
Start-Process -FilePath cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/c $WebDriverIENodeFilePath"
```

Comment: I've just found this, although for my purposes I nedd `/k` as oppoed to `/c`.  Thanks.