# GitHubActions on Windows host (powershell?): exit code of previous lines being ignored

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, github-actions, exit-code

I had this step in a macOS lane:

```
jobs:
  macOS_build:
    runs-on: macOS-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Build in DEBUG and RELEASE mode
      run: ./configure.sh && make DEBUG && make RELEASE
```

Then I successfully split it up this way:

```
jobs:
  macOS_build:
    runs-on: macOS-latest
    steps:
    - name: Build in DEBUG and RELEASE mode
      run: |
        ./configure.sh
        make DEBUG
        make RELEASE
```

This conversion works because if `make DEBUG` fails, `make RELEASE` won't be executed and the whole step is marked as FAILED by GitHubActions.

However, trying to convert this from the Windows lane:

```
jobs:
  windows_build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Build in DEBUG and RELEASE mode
      shell: cmd
      run: configure.bat && make.bat DEBUG && make.bat RELEASE
```

To this:

```
jobs:
  windows_build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Build in DEBUG and RELEASE mode
      shell: cmd
      run: |
        configure.bat
        make.bat DEBUG
        make.bat RELEASE
```

Doesn't work, because strangely enough, only the first line is executed. So I tried trying to change the `shell` attribute to `powershell`:

```
jobs:
  windows_build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Build in DEBUG and RELEASE mode
      shell: powershell
      run: |
        configure.bat
        make.bat DEBUG
        make.bat RELEASE
```

However this fails with:

> configure.bat : The term 'configure.bat' is not recognized as the name
> of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
> spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
> is correct and try again.

Then I saw [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20663591/544947), so I converted it to:

```
jobs:
  windows_build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Build in DEBUG and RELEASE mode
      shell: powershell
      run: |
        & .\configure.bat
        & .\make.bat DEBUG
        & .\make.bat RELEASE
```

This finally launches all batch files independently, however it seems to ignore the exit code (so if configure.bat fails, it still runs the next lines).

Any idea how to separate lines in a GithubActions workflow properly?

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, you'll have to **check the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode) after each call** if you want to take action on the (nonzero) exit code of the most recently executed external program or script:

```
if ($LASTEXITCODE) { exit $LASTEXITCODE }
```

If you want to keep the code small, you could check for intermediate success vs. failure via the [automatic `$?` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1), which is a Boolean that contains `$true` if the most recent command or expression succeeded, which in the case of external programs is inferred if the exit code is `0`:

```
.\configure.bat
if ($?) { .\make.bat DEBUG }
if ($?) { .\make.bat RELEASE }
exit $LASTEXITCODE
```

Note that if you were to use ***PowerShell (Core) 7+***, you could use the `bash`-like approach, since **`&&` and `||`**, the [pipeline-chain operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipeline_Chain_Operators), **are now supported** - as long as you end each statement-internal line with `&&`, you can place each call on its own line:

```
# PSv7+
.\configure.bat && 
.\make.bat DEBUG && 
.\make.bat RELEASE
```

However, note that any nonzero exit code is mapped onto `1` when the PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) is called via `-Command`, which is what I presume happens behind the scenes, and assuming that an external program is called *last*. That is, the *specific* nonzero exit code is lost. If it is of interest, append an `exit $LASTEXITCODE` line to the above.

Comment: your PSv7+ suggestion would leave to square-one, because the initial motivation is to split the line, not leaving it long as you have put it

Comment: @knocte, if this is about readability, you should be able to spread the statement across multiple lines - please seem my update, which now also shows a more concise WinPS solution.

Comment: well it's about readability but without losing functionality (hence my problem with the exit code); thanks, will test your solution